# If $f_n\to f$, $f_n(x_n) = x_n$ and $f(x)=x$, does $x_n\to x$?

Tags: real-analysis, pointwise-convergence, fixed-points

Let $f_1,\dots,f_n,\dots :\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}$ be non increasing continuous functions such that $f_k(0)\geq 0$ and $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f_k(x)<\infty$ for all $k$. Let $f$ that have the same property.

Assume that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}_+$, $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ as $n\to\infty$.

*I proved that* $f_1,\dots,f_n,\dots$ and $f$ have unique fixed points, that we denote $x_1,\dots,x_n,\dots$ and $x_\infty$.

Is it possible to prove that $x_n\to x_\infty$ as $n\to\infty$?

*My idea* is to define $g_k(x) = f_k(x)-x $ and $g(x)=f(x)-x$ (the functions I used to prove existence of a unique fixed points) which are continuous and strictly decreasing. Then I would like to used some kind of continuous inverse theorem *but I do not really see how to do it*.

Maybe it is only true if we assume uniform convergence of $f_n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is that $f_n$ and $f$ are continuous, nonincreasing functions on $[0,\infty)$ with $f_n \to f$ pointwise and $f_n(0) \ge 0$.  Such functions always have unique fixed points on $[0,\infty)$.  For convenience, we can define them on all of $\mathbb R$ by taking $f_n(x) = f_n(0)$ and $f(x) = f(0)$ for $x < 0$.

If $x_\infty$ is the unique fixed point of $f$, take any $\epsilon > 0$ and consider $x_\infty-\epsilon$ and $x_\infty + \epsilon$.  We have
$f(x_\infty - \epsilon) \ge f(x_\infty) = x_\infty$, so for $n$ sufficiently large we have $f_n(x_\infty - \epsilon) > x_\infty - \epsilon $.  Similarly,
for $n$ sufficiently large we have $f_n(x_\infty + \epsilon) < x_\infty+ \epsilon$.  By the Intermediate Value Theorem applied to $f_n(x)-x$, $f_n$ has a fixed point in the interval $(x_\infty - \epsilon, x_\infty + \epsilon)$.  By uniqueness, that fixed point is $x_n$.  Thus we have proven that $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = x_\infty$.

Comment: I am pretty sure that is a simple typo in the answer but the OP says "non increasing" and you state "nondecreasing".

Comment: Thank for the answer. Indeed the functions are non increasing but this shouldn't change the deal.

Comment: @CanTurkun Thanks for catching the typo: I'll edit.